# Resigning from job

Tags: communication

Hi there just need advice.

I'm just wondering do I have to tell my boss that I'm leaving before I hand in my resignation?. Or can I just give my resignation with 3weeks notice?.

Comment: I'd refer to your contract, but without any other details I don't believe we can answer your question here

Comment: We need some details: location, company agreements, etc.  It's impossible to answer this question as is.

Comment: If your contract specifies three weeks notice then generally you don't need to tell them in advance, just hand your resignation letter in and work your three weeks. However, as others have said, this may vary depending on your contract and locale.

Comment: Where are you?  In most places in the US, you can walk off the job at any time without legal trouble, although it's usually not a good idea.  Handing in your resignation is telling your boss that you're leaving in any case.

Comment: You're essentially asking, "Do I have to tell my boss I'm leaving before I tell my boss I'm leaving." *Huh?*

Comment: You want to give notice that you're giving notice?

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you're asking about additional notice as in having this conversation a week before handing in your resignation in writing or, if as Joe says, you're asking if you can hand in your resignation without a conversation at all. Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Answer (score -4):

I would consider it poor etiquette to simply hand in a resignation letter without first having a verbal conversation. There’s no legal reason why you would “have to” do this but it would likely be considered impolite to simply hand them a boilerplate form out of the blue.

Comment: I wouldn't. I'd say half of my resignations were me scheduling a meeting and handing it to him the letter with me saying I've found a better opportunity, and the other were just emails because the boss was unavailable.  A discussion beforehand would be out of the norm.

Comment: Why? The entire point of a resignation letter is to signal your intent to leave. What purpose is there in having a conversation with no documented evidence to the same effect?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I've always seen people have the conversation in the process of giving the letter.

Comment: If your boss decides to make you redundant, do you think he's gonna bother with a friendly chat first? A notice to leave letter is business as usual, as standard as receiving an invoice. Unless, of course, the conversation coincides with the letter, in which case it's a different issue